# Time Series/Predicting discrete values from a finite population

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, poisson-binomial-distribution

I'm at a complete loss as to how to approach this real-world problem.

We have customers that are submitting requests to upgrade their service. I'm trying to create a model that can predict both the number of requests for upgrades that will come, and the amount of service upgrade that will be requested (hopefully by customer and by location for both cases).

The data I have access to is:
the total number of sites that have active service currently, the customers at each site, the amount of upgraded service that was requested when an upgrade order was submitted, and the date the customer submitted their request.

Now, customers submit multiple upgrade requests at one time, which I should think violates the independence assumption for Poisson/Bernoulli/Binomial (negative binomial?) distributions/processes... Also, the sample space is finite, known, and relatively small, so I would think Poisson models can't apply in any case?